# Using bgChange(this.style.backgroundColor)

Tags: html, css

I recently found this code on the w3schools website which allows the user to hover over an object which changed the website background colour. However, in order for the background of the website to change, the object being hovered over must have the same colour background. Is there any way to have the background change colour without the object also having the same background colour?

```html
<script>
function bgChange(bg) {
    document.body.style.background = bg;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Change background color</h2>
<p>Mouse over the squares!</p>

<table style="width:300px;height:100px">
  <tr>
    <td onmouseover="bgChange(this.style.backgroundColor)"
        onmouseout="bgChange('transparent')"
        style="background-color:Khaki">
    </td>
    <td onmouseover="bgChange(this.style.backgroundColor)"
        onmouseout="bgChange('transparent')"
        style="background-color:PaleGreen">
    </td>
    <td onmouseover="bgChange(this.style.backgroundColor)"
        onmouseout="bgChange('transparent')"
        style="background-color:Silver">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Also, sorry if this was poorly phrased.

**EDIT:** I see my mistake now. Oops. I don't get this coding stuff. :)

Comment: Huh? Do you mean you'd like to put something other than `this.style.backgroundColor`, like `red`? Then do it...

Comment: @nicael is it that simple? I understand basically nothing when it comes to coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course it will be the same background color of the element, that is what you are passing to the function and then setting the background color to. If you want to do a different color simply change the value that is being passed to the function

```js
function bgChange(bg) {
    document.body.style.background = bg;
}
```

```html
<h2>Change background color</h2>
<p>Mouse over the squares!</p>

<table style="width:300px;height:100px">
  <tr>
    <td onmouseover="bgChange('red')"
        onmouseout="bgChange('transparent')"
        style="background-color:Khaki">
    </td>
    <td onmouseover="bgChange('blue')"
        onmouseout="bgChange('transparent')"
        style="background-color:PaleGreen">
    </td>
    <td onmouseover="bgChange('green')"
        onmouseout="bgChange('transparent')"
        style="background-color:Silver">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
<table style="width:300px;height:100px">
  <tr>
    <td onmouseover="bgChange('#F0E68C')"
        onmouseout="bgChange('transparent')"
        style="background-color:Khaki">
    </td>
    <td onmouseover="bgChange('#98FB98')"
        onmouseout="bgChange('transparent')"
        style="background-color:PaleGreen">
    </td>
    <td onmouseover="bgChange('#C0C0C0')"
        onmouseout="bgChange('transparent')"
        style="background-color:Silver">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```